# React does not automatically re-render after refreshing browser

Tags: reactjs, webpack, vagrant, webpack-dev-server, jsx

I have to restart my server every-time to see new changes to be reflected on the html. I believe that react should be able to automatically re-render when the js/jsx component codes are changed.

I am currently running my server on vagrant.

I have tried adding "--hot" and "--watch" separately in package.json.

Thanks

Comment: what are you using to serve up your javascript?

Comment: I am using webpack to serve up my javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the webpack-dev-server to serve up your JS. That's what provides the hot-reloading feature.

i.e. you should be building your project similarly to this (from package.json):

`"start": "node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --inline --content-base dist --history-api-fallback"`

and your webpack.config.js should include something similar to:

```
devServer: {
  colors: true,
  historyApiFallback: true,
  inline: false,
  port: 8080,
  hot: true
},
```